# Unable to dynamically change value for static label column header

Tags: jasper-reports

I am unable to dynamically change the column header values during run time while creating a jasper report. Why do I keep getting string to boolean cast exception everytime I assign the value to table element's column header??

I have a column header that is a part of the table element. And this table and its dataset are not a part of the main data set. I want to the column header to change dynamically based on values in the main dataset. The main dataset and sub data set return different resultsets

The steps I followed were:

1. create a variable called v1_enabed (string) and v1_display(string) in the main dataset. I also assigned the required fields(from the main data set) to these variables
2. I created a parameter p1(string) in subdataset
3. I use the subdataset fields for table creation. I used the table element.
4. I go the table and map the parameter p1(string) to the table. And I assign the expression `($V{v1_enabled} == Character.toString('1'))  ? $V{v1_display} :  $V{v1_display}` to it

Until here whenever I run the report, I do not get any error.

5. Now, I go the table. Pick up the 5th column and assign this in the print when expression section -- $P(p1)

Now, comes the error:  `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean`

How do I solve this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the jrxml of this case.

Comment: You need to show your jrxml so we see all declarations or we can't answer, in specific are you using groovy?